# In SQL Server, order by date not showing all dates in desc order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to show daily collected amount in admin panel of one e-commerce portal in descending order of date. But when I am trying to showing it will showing daily collected amount but showing randomly.

```
Dates       Amount
------------------
30/12/2017  36010   
30/11/2017  42780   
29/12/2017  23090   
29/11/2017  66060   
28/12/2017   4700   
28/11/2017  84370
```

But I have to show this in below order

```
Dates       Amount
--------------------
30/12/2017  36010
29/12/2017  23090
28/12/2017   4700       
30/11/2017  42780   
29/11/2017  66060   
28/11/2017  84370
```

This is my sample code , please correct me, where I am wrong

```
SELECT
    (SUM(MonthAmount) + SUM(LateFine)) AS DailyCollection, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ApprovedDate, 103) AS InboxDate  
FROM
    [dbo].[SlipDetails] 
WHERE
    ApprovedByAdmin = 'A' 
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ApprovedDate, 103) 
ORDER BY 
    InboxDate DESC
```

Comment: Use `....Order by ApprovedDate desc`

Comment: Already tried this but its showing same out put which is showing currently.

Comment: What is the datatype of `ApprovedDate` ?

Comment: Little confused here. The OP's query shows the name of the columnb is `InboxDate`, which is derived from the column `ApprovedDate`. The OP's sample data, however, has the column `Dates`. Where did that come from? Are the query and Sample data actually related?

Comment: Datatype is **datetime** for ApprovedDate.

Comment: I am using datetime format but I have to show in dates in DD/MM/YYYY format for that we convert into string/text

Comment: As I said in my answer, why not do the formatting in your presentation layer? This preserves the data type in your query, and the presentation layer knows the value is a date as well.

Comment: **InboxDate** alias of that columns ApprovedDate.

Comment: @AtharvJoshi I know `InboxDate` is an alias, but your **sample data** has the columns `Dates` and `Amount`. Neither of these columns or aliases are in your provided query, hence my question .

Comment: Not possible to do in Presentation layer because I have to show sum of daily collected amount. If I do that calculation part in presentation layer it taking too much time to process.

Comment: @AtharvJoshi - Check my updated answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select (sum(MonthAmount) + sum(LateFine)) as DailyCollection, 
CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103) as InboxDate  
from [dbo].[SlipDetails] where ApprovedByAdmin='A' 
group by CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103) 
order by CONVERT(DATE,  CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103),103) desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `....Order by ApprovedDate desc`

You are sorting a string/text value not a date value (because you are converting the `ApprovedDate` to string before the sorting)

If you want the date field in that specified format you can use the below method. ie you can convert that formatted date string to `Date` datatype for sorting only.

```
select (sum(MonthAmount) + sum(LateFine)) as DailyCollection, 
CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103) as InboxDate  
from [dbo].[SlipDetails] where ApprovedByAdmin='A' 
group by CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103) 
order by CONVERT(DATE,  CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103),103) desc
```

Note :- As mentioned by `@Larnu`, *better keep your data types as they are, and change display formats in your presentation layer.*

Comment: I am using datetime format but I have to show in dates in DD/MM/YYYY format for that we convert into string/text .

Comment: @AtharvJoshi, changed, plz chk now.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below :

```
select DailyCollection, InboxDate from (
    select (sum(MonthAmount) + sum(LateFine)) as DailyCollection, 
    CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103) as InboxDate  
    from [dbo].[SlipDetails] where ApprovedByAdmin='A' 
    group by CONVERT(varchar(11),ApprovedDate,103)
) as T order by convert(datetime, InboxDate, 103) desc
```

As you are converting your `datetime` column to `varchar`, you will not get the desired result if you order with the converted `varchar` column, in that case, you can use derived table and converted back the `varchar` column to `datetime` while doing the order like i did above.

Comment: If the datatype of 'ApprovedDate` is datetime, then there is no reason that the above query doesn't order the dates correctly.

Comment: I tried many time for this query but getting error of aggregate function.
**Column "dbo.SlipDetails.ApprovedDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: The Op would need to do `GROUP BY ApprovedDate ORDER BY ApprovedDate`. Grouping on the Converted value will give the above error the OP has provided in his comment.

Comment: @AtharvJoshi - That's correct, so you can use the updated query in that case, please check

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are converting your `date` to a `varchar` and then sorting on it. The order of a `varchar` is VERY different to that of a `date`. For example, in date terms, `16/01/2018` is before `01/12/2020`. in `varchar` terms, however, `01/12/2020` is **before** `16/01/2018`. Why? Because `0` is before `1`.

Keep your data types as they are, and worry about display formats in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ordering is being performed based on varchar datatype.
You Need to order records based on date data type.